# Drupal content type node not overwriting the default node.tpl.php

Tags: theming, nodes

I have a content type with a machine name of 'school' after reading the documentation I should be able to just create a node-school.tpl.php to toy with the output of this in my theme.

Yet it does not seem to be overwriting it. I am trying to hack something together and I am using the twitter bootstrap Drupal theme.

Comment: Drupal6 or Drupal7?

Answer (score 2):

If its drupal6 site then it is `node-school.tpl.php` . If Druapl7 then tpl should be `node--school.tpl.php`.

After Creating the files you need to clear the performance cache once.

Comment: Argh it was the performance cache doing me over. Thanks for the super fast response!

Comment: Most Welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be **node--school.tpl.php** for drupal 7 and **node-school.tpl.php** for drupal 6. And make sure to clear your cache

Comment: In addition to this, check this: https://drupal.org/node/1089656

Comment: Argh it was the performance cache doing me over. Thanks again for the super fast response!